# Material shading nodes: Different shaders for flat vs. curved faces

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I have a cylinder and I want the curved outside to have one simple diffuse shader, and the two flat sides to have a different diffuse shader. How would I do that?

I was stuck on believing that this is connected to the "Auto Smooth" (including the angle limit) function that already comes with Blender. I thought the basics are there because, the way I understand it, Auto Smooth almost does the thing I want: It shades faces differently, depending on their outer vertices' normals.
[image]

I tried playing around with the normals Input:
[image]

But this is dependant on the rotation of the object. The lower flat face, the one that's not visible in this screenshot, is still blue. And if I rotate the object, everything is messed up.

---

**EDIT: Possible solution**

Okay so I asked elsewhere, and I got a promising response. Now I'll be honest, I just barely passed linear algebra back in university, more than 10 years ago by sheer dumb luck, so I don't know exactly what these nodes do. But using vector absolute and vector dot product nodes seems like it might be the solution to my problem. This is the current node setup:
[image]

And this is the result. I have to verify if it works like I want it to more thoroughly, but maybe this is the solution!

[image]

Also, I updated the title. It's more fitting to what I'm actually trying to find out here now.

Comment: The smoothing is working on the edges, not the faces... the effect is only looking as if a smooth surface extends from one face to the other because the edge inbetween is smoothed. Which means, it is not like the side of the cylinder is shaded smooth, and the top and bottom are shaded flat so that you have a criterion to switch from one to the other...

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
So, would you say what I'm trying to do is basically impossible?

Comment: I guess so, because the criterion which you are looking for to decide which face gets which shader does not exist. As long as you have planar faces, each face of the cylinder (or other meshes) by itself is flat, the top and bottom ones as well as the side faces. It's the edge angle the _Auto Smooth_ function is looking for (and which you set as _Angle_ in the options). So it is not possible in general as a recreation of the _Auto Smooth_ function. In your special case of course you could differentiate between face normals pointing up or down and the others pointing to the sides...

Comment: ...but if you are looking for something that works only in this special case, it would be much easier to simply apply different shaders to different faces manually.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem - why do you want to avoid using geometry nodes? The example is fine, but can you also explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thank you for the reply! I updated my OP with some more information on what I'm trying to do and what I've done so far. Also, I should probably mention, I'm by no means an expert, but I'm not a complete beginner either. And I've been stuck on this problem for like a full month now. That's why I resorted to asking the internet.

Comment: The problem is, the shader is evaluated per point and it's just not given the information about the angles of edges constructing the face the point belongs to. You have a **true normal** of the face, if you want to override the smooth shading back to flat shading, and that's about it. You still didn't mention why geometry nodes are out of the question or what is the end-goal… For a vertical cylinder you can use a true normal of the face to differentiate top and bottom (flat) faces from the rest of the cylinder. You could also multiply the normal by $<1, 1, 0>$ to flatten it…

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady well, I'd 90% prefer a material shading node based solution but if it's easy to do with geometry nodes, I guess I can at least look how that works.
Can I ask you how you'd do it with geometry nodes?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady And by "do it", I mean basically apply one shader to flat surfaces and another shader to curved surfaces

Comment: @RichardM90 If I remember correctly, I think you can actually set individual to shaded smooth or flat in _Edit Mode_. I do not know right now if you can read that information easily. But that's why I said you have to clarify what you really want if we should help you. When you said "re-create the _Auto Smooth_ function", that is something different because all faces are shaded smooth then, just some edges are treated as sharp. So edge angle could be used to make a decision how to shade the face, but I have no idea for this at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused about how "auto smooth" works. It doesn't make some parts smooth and some parts flat. Everything is smoothed, but the effect (as Gordon already said) is limited across the edges above the "Auto smooth angle" threshold. This is why one alternative to Auto smooth is using "Split Edges" modifier, and that's how you should think about it.

Take a look at this cylinder with poked flat faces (just for explicit triangulation, not related to the issue) and then bent so now there are still 3 separate surfaces: top, side, bottom, you can still see the top and side, and they are still separated - both are smooth, but (visually) separated:

[image]

Now, a shader is run for each point separately. The point somewhere in the middle of an area couldn't possible know, that somewhere there is an edge, and this edge makes a full "circle" on the surface of the mesh, therefore separating the area of this point, out of the rest of the mesh, and the shader of this area should be some specific shader… Consider the case below - the threshold has been increased, so now a few edges no longer stop the flow of the normal:

[image]

So are the areas above still separate areas or now they are one area? Assuming the latter, you can use geometry nodes to physically split the edge using the angle threshold, and then assign materials based on island index:

[image]

How did I know which material will go where? I didn't. I first named them Top, Side, Bottom, in that order, then I tested, saw it's wrong, and renamed them to be correct. You could improve the geometry nodes setup to somehow sort the mesh islands…

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'll try this for sure, but in the meantime, I updated my OP again with a possible solution. I have to verify it still.

Comment: Sorry. Markus.. when I fire up in the morning to review posts, some answers don't show up... I must remember to refresh.

Comment: @RobinBetts no problem :D

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to [Markus' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299768/35559) .. again..

For a more general definition of what constitutes a 'flat' region .. (all the faces are flat), you could reach for something like 3DS 's 'Smoothing Groups'

This GN modifier splits a copy of the mesh by edge angle, and stores the normalized index of the resulting mesh-islands on face-corners of the original:

[image]

The resulting 0-1 attribute could be used in a material:

[image]

Separating  islands:

[image]

Unlike the 3DS case, where groups are manually defined using *faces*, this is vulnerable to islands not being completely bounded by sharp *edges*, so won't be the same, but could still have its uses.

[image]